# How can I use SensorManager.getOrientation for tilt controls like "My Paper Plane"?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, tilt

The Android game [My Paper Plane](http://www.appbrain.com/app/my-paper-plane-2-%283d%29/com.wavecade.mypaperplane_x) is a great example of how to implement tilt controls, but I've been struggling to understand how I can do something similar.

I have the following example that uses [getOrientation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) from the SensorManager. The whole thing is on [pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/c1MNT5x7). It just prints the orientation values to text fields. Here is the most relevant snippet:

```
private void computeOrientation() {
    if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(m_rotationMatrix, null,
                                        m_lastMagFields, m_lastAccels)) {
        SensorManager.getOrientation(m_rotationMatrix, m_orientation);

        /* 1 radian = 57.2957795 degrees */
        /* [0] : yaw, rotation around z axis
         * [1] : pitch, rotation around x axis
         * [2] : roll, rotation around y axis */
        float yaw = m_orientation[0] * 57.2957795f;
        float pitch = m_orientation[1] * 57.2957795f;
        float roll = m_orientation[2] * 57.2957795f;

        /* append returns an average of the last 10 values */
        m_lastYaw = m_filters[0].append(yaw);
        m_lastPitch = m_filters[1].append(pitch);
        m_lastRoll = m_filters[2].append(roll);
        TextView rt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.roll);
        TextView pt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pitch);
        TextView yt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yaw);
        yt.setText("azi z: " + m_lastYaw);
        pt.setText("pitch x: " + m_lastPitch);
        rt.setText("roll y: " + m_lastRoll);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the values this spits out look like nonsense, or at least there's no way to isolate which type of motion the user performed. I've drawn a diagram to indicate the 2 types of motion that I'd like to detect - 1. "tilt" for pitch and 2. "rotate" for roll/steering:

[image: Figure 1. Pitch and roll]

(That's an isometric-ish view of a phone in landscape mode, of course)

When I tilt the phone forwards and backwards along its long axis - shown by 1. - I expected only 1 of the values to change much, but all of them seem to change drastically. Similarly, if I rotate the phone about an imaginary line that comes out of the screen - shown in 2. - I'd hope that only the roll value changes, but all the values change a lot.

The problem is when I calibrate my game - which means recording the current values of the angles x, y and z - I later don't know how to interpret incoming updated angles to say "ok, looks like you have tilted the phone and you want to roll 3 degrees left". It's more like "ok, you've moved the phone and you're a-tiltin' and a-rollin' at the same time", even if the intent was only a roll. Make sense?

Any ideas? I've tried using remapCoordinateSystem to see if changing the axis has any effect. No joy. I think I'm missing something fundamental with this :-(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You mixed the accelerator and megnetic sensor arrays. The code should be:

```
if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(m_rotationMatrix, null,
                                    m_lastAccels, m_lastMagFields)) {
```

Check out [`getRotationMatrix(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix(float[],%20float[],%20float[],%20float[]))

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing. Also: A BIG, FAT THANK YOU! I don't know how many hours I've wasted over the last few days and weeks obsessing over this. Yes, using the API as it was intended makes things work a lot better.

Comment: I know the feeling ;) For this kind of problems a second pair of eyes is really helpful.

Comment: I see that this post seems to be answered, and is a bit old, but I've done a writeup of essentially what you're looking for here: [http://blog.samsandberg.com/2015/05/10/tilt-for-android/](http://blog.samsandberg.com/2015/05/10/tilt-for-android/) - hope it helps someone!