# How to detect phone tilt?

Tags: android, rotation, tilt

How to determine the angle of the phone orientation in the one plane?

Now I make it through SensorManager:

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mOrientation = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);

...

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    xy_angle = event.values[0]; 
    xz_angle = event.values[1]; 
    zy_angle = event.values[2];
```

Here I get different angles, but I need only one angle, which varies with the rotation of the phone, while driving along the blue line.

How calc or how get this angle?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCElj.jpg]

[How can I use SensorManager.getOrientation for tilt controls like "My Paper Plane"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576493/how-can-i-use-sensormanager-getorientation-for-tilt-controls-like-my-paper-plan) - similar question here, but I don't understand how author solve his problem.

Comment: Please share the solution if you got one

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [`SensorManager.getOrientation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29).

Answer (score 2):

I see that this post is a bit old, so maybe it's been answered by now, but `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` is now deprecated in favor of [SensorManager.getOrientation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html).

I've done a full writeup of essentially what you're looking for here: http://blog.samsandberg.com/2015/05/10/tilt-for-android/

Hope it helps someone looking for the same thing!

Comment: Sorry for that - blog was riddled with spam so I took it down until I had a chance to fix it. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

The author of that question solved his problem by switching his parameter order:

```
 if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(m_rotationMatrix, null,
                                    m_lastMagFields, m_lastAccels)) {
```

to:

```
if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(m_rotationMatrix, null,
                                m_lastAccels, m_lastMagFields)) {
```